# How to call Dynamics 365 web services using DiscoveryWebProxyClient class object ? (Using OAuth authentication)

Tags: oauth, dynamics-365

Can someone please help how to make use of "**DiscoveryWebProxyClient**" class object ?

I have already registered a web/api application in my "Azure Active Directory".

```
AuthenticationContext auth = new AuthenticationContext("login.microsoftonline.com[myTenantId]");

ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential("[ClientId]", "[ClinetSecret]");
string token = auth.AcquireToken("[myDynamics365_URL]", clientCred).AccessToken;

using (var orgService = new OrganizationWebProxyClient(GetServiceUrl("[myDynamics365_URL]+/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc/web?SdkClientVersion=9.0"), false))
{
   orgService .HeaderToken = token;
   var request = new OrganizationRequest(){RequestName = "WhoAmI"};
   var response= orgService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse;
}
```

Using this above token [by ADAL], I am able to get response for "**WhoAmI**" request successfully.

Using DiscoveryWebProxyClient:

```
DiscoveryWebProxyClient discoveryWebProxyClient = new DiscoveryWebProxyClient(new Uri("disco.crm8.dynamics.com/.../web"))
{
   HeaderToken = token,
};
RetrieveOrganizationsRequest orgRequest = new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest();
var discResponse = discoveryWebProxyClient.Execute(orgRequest);}
```

When I am trying to get the response for "RetrieveOrganizationsRequest" using same token [By ADAL], I am getting the following exception.

**Exception:** *The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Bearer error=access_denied, error_description=Authentication fail. Ticket id [-----------], authorization_uri=login.windows.net/.../authorize, resource_id=disco.crm8.dynamics.com'.*

**Can someone please help me how to make request using "DiscoveryWebProxyClient" ?**